# Page Not Found when executing a popup screen?

Tags: php, popup, http-status-code-404

I have an input element that's configured as a button (see code below). When clicked, it opens a popup window.

It works perfectly on almost every site its installed on. However, on this particular site, whenever its clicked, it goes to the WordPress "page not found", 404 page.

What could cause this?

```
<input 
    type="button" 
    id="testUpload" 
    value="Upload" 
    onclick="window.open(
        'http://www.mysite.com/wp-content/themes/mytheme/uploader.php?action=test',
        'popup',
        'width=330,height=235,scrollbars=no,resizable=no,toolbar=no,directories=no,location=no,menubar=no,status=no'
        ); 
    return false" 
/>
```

I've verified that the uploader.php file is present.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you reach the link by manually entering it into the browser's address bar?

- If not, then you're dealing with problems with the uploader.php (permissions?)
- If yes, there are some Javascript-related problems.

Comment: Nope. Can't access it directly. It resolves to the 404 page either way. I'm going to get FTP access to the site to check the file out.